# Unable to capture Redux-form Field values with handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, forms, jsx, redux-form

I am trying to integrate Redux-form v6 into my project, however no matter how closely I try to replicate the example code, I cannot get a working redux-form.

Everything seems to be connected properly, however the handleSubmit function does not capture any of the values from my form fields.

Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. My code is below.

Starting with the reducer, nothing seems to be the matter here.

```jsx
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
});
```

Then, I use a container component to connect the form component to redux form, which decorates the form component nicely with all the Redux-form function.

CreateCompany.js

```jsx
import CreateCompany from '../components/create_company';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'company-submission'
})(CreateCompany);
```

The actual form then looks like this:

CreateCompany.jsx

```jsx
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(values => {console.log("values",values)})}>

  <div>
    <label htmlFor="group">Group Name (Required)</label>
    <Field name="group" component={FormInput} type="text"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <Field
      name="group-type"
      component={DropDownSelect}
      selectOptions={this.state.groupTypes}
      id="group-type"
    />
    <label>Group Type</label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Log In</button>

</form>
```

The text input stateless functions supplied to the Field component.

FormInput.js 
(Note: I had to include `{...input.value}` in the input tag to be able to type into the field. In the example code, only `{...input}` is used.)

```jsx
import React from 'react';

const FormInput = ({ id, type, className, input }) => {
  className = className || "";
  id = id || "";
  return (
    <input id={id} {...input.value} type={type} className={className}/>
  )
}

export default FormInput;
```

DropDownSelect.js

```jsx
import React from 'react';

const DropDownSelect = ({ input, selectOptions, id }) => {
  const renderSelectOptions = (selectOption) => (
    <option key={selectOption} value={selectOption}>{selectOption}</option>
  )
  return (
    <select id={id} {...input}>
      {selectOptions.map(renderSelectOptions)}
    </select>
  );
}

export default DropDownSelect;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: does the handleSubmit function get executed?

Comment: Yes it does and it logs an empty object to the console as it is instructed to do so by the function I pass into handleSubmit

Answer (score 0):

`handleSubmit` should be defined outside of you `CreateCompany` component and passed to it via props. Check out [examples](http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/examples/submitValidation/)